# Until sentences

Tags: grammar

She usually does not leave for work until she finished all her chores.

(a) finishes

(b) has finished

(c) had finished

(d) no improvement

Please ans this question I am confused in option A and B

Answer (score 1):

**Michael Swan** comments on this issue in *Practical English Usage*:

> **tenses with until**
>
> Present tenses are used to refer to the future after **until**.
>   *I'll wait until she gets here.* (**NOT** ... until she will get here.) Present perfect and past perfect tenses can emphasise the idea
>   of completion.
>   *You're not going home until you've finished that report. I waited until the rain had stopped.*

So, the correct variants are a) and b)